# type-class difficult inference

Tags: haskell, types, typeclass

I want to make following type inferable :

```
class Lit a
instance Lit Int
instance Lit Float

class App a b
instance App Float b

f :: (Lit a, App a b) => a -> b -- a should be Float
```

I know this sample cannot be inferred `a` to `Float` because type class be not closed, at least.

What should I do to achieve the purpose?

Additionally, the thing I want to do is constructing Typed EDSL using TH and Haskell Type Checker. for example if the variable (Int or Float) "p" are multiplied by Float, I want to infer "p" to Float. So the solution to this is also welcomed.

Comment: As stated, it is unsolvable for the reason you mention: typeclasses are open. You could instead try to use functional dependencies or type families, if those make your own goal possible.

Comment: that's right, and I tried some different style of this code, but any try didn't success...I'm wondering this can be solved using closed type families, but I don't know how to do.

Comment: Closed type families are not enough, you need injective type families as well, which are coming Real Soon Now (tm).

Answer (score 2):

It is not very clear what problem you are trying to solve with this code, but as @chi stated, you can try FunDeps

```
  {-# LANGUAGE FunctionalDependencies, FlexibleInstances #-}

  class Lit a
  instance Lit Int
  instance Lit Float

  class App a b | b -> a
  instance App Float b

  f :: (Lit a, App a b) => a -> Maybe b
  f x = Nothing
```

or TypeFamilies

```
{-# LANGUAGE TypeFamilies, FlexibleInstances #-}

class Lit a
instance Lit Int
instance Lit Float

class App res where
  type Arg res

instance App res where
  type Arg res = Float

f :: App b => Arg b -> Maybe b
f x = Nothing
```

Using FunDeps in this example is more concise, but in my experience TypeFamilies + GADTs solutions are more straightforward and manageable for type-level programming.

Comment: Sorry, in my case, there's like a `instance App Double b`... I reconsidered this problem and concluded my problem cannot be solved, so I decided to write type explicitly. Thanks.